# Error while reading YAML file in python

Tags: python, opencv, yaml, pyyaml

I have a `yaml` file that looks like this:

```
%YAML 1.0
temp: !!opencv-matrix
 rows: 2
 cols: 23
 dt: f
 data: [ 3.35620789e+02, 3.64299591e+02, 3.95790131e+02,
   4.39863068e+02, 4.68664948e+02, 4.93518127e+02, 4.17159943e+02,
   4.21060364e+02, 3.99990234e+02, 4.17867157e+02, 4.34151215e+02,
   3.56201202e+02, 3.77741028e+02, 3.87051544e+02, 3.76879913e+02,
   4.42746796e+02, 4.52483917e+02, 4.73469604e+02, 4.52954742e+02,
   3.78402283e+02, 4.17679047e+02, 4.50588501e+02, 4.16388153e+02,
   9.05276794e+01, 9.21245193e+01, 1.02799362e+02, 9.93146744e+01,
   8.40704346e+01, 7.84236526e+01, 1.15820358e+02, 1.76747055e+02,
   1.61153061e+02, 1.68130676e+02, 1.58446228e+02, 1.07421455e+02,
   1.03407494e+02, 1.05380608e+02, 1.08374542e+02, 1.01048920e+02,
   9.76309204e+01, 9.83933716e+01, 1.02486870e+02, 1.71890350e+02,
   1.81417206e+02, 1.66303802e+02, 1.95539871e+02 ]
```

It is basically an `opencv matrix` and I have created the file in a `c++` code. Now I want to read this file in `python` and I have this code:

```
import yaml
with open("reference_3d.yml") as fin:
     rfr = yaml.load(fin.read())
```

But when I run the code, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "scatter_plot.py", line 15, in <module>
rfr = yaml.load(fin.read())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 71, in  load
return loader.get_single_data()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 37, in get_single_data
node = self.get_single_node()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 35, in  get_single_node
if not self.check_event(StreamEndEvent):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 98, in check_event
self.current_event = self.state()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 157, in parse_implicit_document_start
return self.parse_document_start()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 174, in parse_document_start
self.peek_token().start_mark)
yaml.parser.ParserError: expected '<document start>', but found '<scalar>'
in "<string>", line 2, column 2:
 temp: !!opencv-matrix
 ^
```

Any idea how should I resolve this error?

Comment: @karthikr Please be careful closing questions as duplicate. The differences between the YAML file in the question you indicate as a duplicate, and the file in this question, and the other circumstances are subtle, but significant. There is a better way then taking an axe and cutting of the first two lines to solve **this** question that doesn't apply to the one you indicate as duplicate. So a possible answer can only go here, and cannot be added at the duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that your C++ generates (invalid) YAML 1.0 and that you try to parse that with a Python parser that can handle most of YAML 1.1.

The [YAML 1.0 specification](http://yaml.org/spec/1.0/http://) doesn't have many examples, but the directive for documents states that the optional [c-ns-directive](http://yaml.org/spec/1.0/#c-ns-directive) should come in the document header **after** the document start ([rules 48 and 49](http://yaml.org/spec/1.0/#c-ns-directive)) and the specification [clearly states that its form should be `%YAML:1.0`](http://yaml.org/spec/1.0/#id2558757). Therefore a correct YAML 1.0 document should start with:

```
---
%YAML:1.0
```

However, even if this was output correctly PyYAML would not be able to read this older YAML version file.

Since the latest YAML specification (1.2) is from 2009, the best thing you can do is to switch both your C++ program and your Python program to a 1.2 compatible library library. On [yaml.org](http://yaml.org/) it is indicated that for C++ this would be [`yaml-cpp`](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/) and for Python this would have to be [`ruamel.yaml`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) (disclaimer: I am the author of that package).

The YAML file will look like (`yaml-cpp` might change the tag and maybe even the rest of the dump):

```
%YAML 1.2
---
temp: !!opencv-matrix
 rows: 2
 cols: 23
 dt: f
 data: [ 3.35620789e+02, 3.64299591e+02, 3.95790131e+02,
   4.39863068e+02, 4.68664948e+02, 4.93518127e+02, 4.17159943e+02,
   4.21060364e+02, 3.99990234e+02, 4.17867157e+02, 4.34151215e+02,
   3.56201202e+02, 3.77741028e+02, 3.87051544e+02, 3.76879913e+02,
   4.42746796e+02, 4.52483917e+02, 4.73469604e+02, 4.52954742e+02,
   3.78402283e+02, 4.17679047e+02, 4.50588501e+02, 4.16388153e+02,
   9.05276794e+01, 9.21245193e+01, 1.02799362e+02, 9.93146744e+01,
   8.40704346e+01, 7.84236526e+01, 1.15820358e+02, 1.76747055e+02,
   1.61153061e+02, 1.68130676e+02, 1.58446228e+02, 1.07421455e+02,
   1.03407494e+02, 1.05380608e+02, 1.08374542e+02, 1.01048920e+02,
   9.76309204e+01, 9.83933716e+01, 1.02486870e+02, 1.71890350e+02,
   1.81417206e+02, 1.66303802e+02, 1.95539871e+02 ]
```

And this you can do:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml = YAML()

with open('reference_3d.yaml') as fin:
    rfr = yaml.load(fin)

print(rfr['temp']['data'][rfr['temp']['cols']-1])
```

to get the last value of the first data row ( `416.388153` )

If you cannot, or are unwilling to change your C++ program, then just use `ruamel.yaml` and skip the first line of the YAML file:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml = YAML()

with open('reference_3d.yaml') as fin:
    fin.readline()
    rfr = yaml.load(fin)

print(rfr['temp']['data'][rfr['temp']['cols']-1])
```

Please note that the recommended extension for files containing YAML documents has been `.yaml` since at least September 2006.

Comment: the latest build of ```ruamel.yaml``` may have removed the ```round_trip_load()``` method, the above code throws an ```AttributeError```

Comment: The *function* `round_trip_load()` (it was never a method) was deprecated several years ago.